# Below code is to display menus using json.But it is not working

Tags: jquery, json

This code takes values from json and then outputs a menu bar but i am facing problems .
I want to display the menubar including its submenus which is dynamic instead of static.
All the values must be in json and the output in UI accroding to the array in json string

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="json/jsondata.json"></script> -->
<script>

var data = "[{'text': 'Chocolate Beverage','id': '1','parentid': '-1'}, {'id': '2','parentid': '1','text': 'Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '3','parentid': '1','text': 'Peppermint Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '4','parentid': '1','text': 'Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '5','parentid': '1','text': 'White Hot Chocolate'}]";



var builddata = function () {
    var source = [];
    var items = [];

    // build hierarchical source.
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var label = item["text"];
        var parentid = item["parentid"];
        var id = item["id"];

        if (items[parentid]) {
            var item = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
            if (!items[parentid].items) {
                items[parentid].items = [];
            }
            items[parentid].items[items[parentid].items.length] = item;
            items[id] = item;
        }
        else {
            items[id] = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
            source[id] = items[id];
        }
    }
    return source;
}
var source = builddata();


var buildUL = function (parent, items) {
    $.each(items, function () {
        if (this.label) {
            // create LI element and append it to the parent element.
            var li = $("<li>" + this.label + "</li>");
            li.appendTo(parent);
            // if there are sub items, call the buildUL function.
            if (this.items && this.items.length > 0) {
                var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                ul.appendTo(li);
                buildUL(ul, this.items);
            }
        }
    });
}
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
ul.appendTo("#jqxMenu");
buildUL(ul, source);

$("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ width: '600', height: '30px'});
alert(8);
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- $("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ width: '600', height: '30px'}); -->
    <div id='jqxMenu'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
var data = "[{'text': 'Chocolate Beverage','id': '1','parentid': '-1'}, {'id': '2','parentid': '1','text': 'Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '3','parentid': '1','text': 'Peppermint Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '4','parentid': '1','text': 'Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate'}, {'id': '5','parentid': '1','text': 'White Hot Chocolate'}]";
data  = JSON.parse(data );
```

you need to parse string as json.

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

You never parsed the JSON text into an object. In the state you have it, it's just a raw string. Use [jQuery.parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) to parse that JSON string into an object.